# Prove that R is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let R be a relation on $\mathbb{Z} × ( \mathbb{Z}  \setminus \{0\} )$ where 
>   $$( a, b ) R ( c, d ) \Leftrightarrow ad = bc.$$  Prove that R is an equivalence relation.  Describe the distinct equivalence classes of R in terms of rational numbers and justify your answer.

I copy and pasted this question from the textbook, sorry if the formatting is weird. Anyways, I don't understand the $\mathbb{Z}  \setminus \{0\}$ part of the question. If you're willing to solve the problem, can you somewhat explain your answer? Thanks I'm very new to this stuff.

Comment: $\Bbb Z-\{0\}$ is the set of all *non-zero* integers

Comment: You should have written $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$. Anyway, it's just the set of the non-zero integer numbers. What's about it that you don't understand?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos both notations are correct and frequently used

Comment: @Math_QED The notation chosen by the OP is ambiguous. What is $\{1,2\}+\{2,3\}$? Usually, it means $\{1+2,1+3,2+2,2+3\}$. But then, what is $\{-1,0,0\}-\{0\}$? Is it $\{-1-0,0-0,1-0\}$? Or is it $\{-1,1\}$?

Comment: I agree that it is ambiguous. But many authors (E.g. Apostol, Bloch, ..) use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You elements are pairs $(a,b)$ where $b \ne 0$.

$(a,b)R(c,d)$ means that $ad = bc$

TO be an equivalence relationship the must be:

1) Reflexive:

For all $(a,b)$ we must have $(a,b) = R(a,b)$

So we must prove that $ab = ab$ for all $(a,b)$.

2) Symetric:

If $(a,b) R (c,d)$ it must be true that $(c,d) R (a,b)$

So we must prove that if $ad = cb$ then $cb = ad$.

3) Transitive:

If $(a,b) R (cd)$ and $(c,d)R (e,f)$ it must be true that $(a,b)R(e,f)$.

So we must prove that if $ad=cb$ and $cf=ed$ then $af=eb$.

Comment: I did figure it out in the end after hours of trying to learn this stuff, however, thanks for your help! I didn't know people replied so quickly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to keep definitions in mind when you're solving such questions. For a relation to be an equivalence class it must be:

1) Symmetric: $\forall (a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}\times {\mathbb{Z}\ -{0}}$

if $(a,b)R(c,d) \implies ad=bc \implies bc=ad \implies (c,d)R(a,b)$

2) Reflexive:
$\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\times {\mathbb{Z}\ -{0}}$

$ab= ab \implies (a,b)R(a,b) \implies$ R is reflexive

3) Transitive: consider $(a,b), (c,d), (e,f) \in \mathbb{Z}\times {\mathbb{Z}\ -{0}}$

If $(a,b)R(c,d) and (c,d)R(e,f) \implies ad=bc and cf=de \implies c=de/f \implies  ad=b(de/f) \implies fad=bde \implies fa = be \implies af=be \implies (a,b)R(e,f)$

Then, R is an equivalence relation.

Try proving the other part on your own. Remember, definitions are very important!

Comment: Thanks for aiding me on this question! I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to ask anything if you need any further help with this.